# Schema changes with replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, schema

What are the steps to make a schema change to a SQL Server 2005 database using transactional replication?

I'm trying to add a database column. I thought if I removed the article for the table, made the schema change, and then added the article for the table back that the schema change would replicate. I am now getting the following error every minute or so:

> SQL Server errors
>   Replication-Replication Distribution
>   Subsystem: agent [jobname] failed.
>   Invalid column name 'NewColumn'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize the subscriber from a snapshot to pick up the schema change.